# how do i add links to search suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a fairly new at coding with js and i only have a brief self taught knowledge in html.
any help would be very appreciated, thank you.

This is the javascript for a search box with an autocomplete function. i am asking as to how i can add links for each variables.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input.autocomplete').autocomplete({
        data: {
            "Single Seats": null,
            "Multiple Seats": null,
            "Beds": null,
            "Entertainment": null,
            "Tables": null,
            "Storage": null,
            "Sets": null,
            "Other": null
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: what kind of link, can you give more details

Comment: i would like it to link it to an html file. it's for a search box with search suggestions, when i input some texts like "B"  suggestions would dropdown like "Beds" and "Tables", i can click the suggestion Beds and it will autocomplete and fill the input field with the suggestion i clicked on, but pressing enter doesn't do anything because i don't know how to make it go to the html file for beds. similar to using href to a word.

Comment: so you are trying to implement a "AUTOCOMPLETE"  input, so when the user  select value using 'ENTER" key, it will redirect to some kind of url, right

Comment: Right! i think the autocomplete is mostly done. kinda like how google search engine works entering or clicking suggestions transfer you to a different html.

Comment: check my solution, is it what you are looking for ?? or do you need any change ?\

Comment: sorry for being a newbie at this but is $( "#tags") for the id? and is Tags in var availableTags referring to the same id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the snippet, this will redirect to the link attached to the autocomplete array. 
Here the autocomplete array has object with value and url, page will be redirected to appropriate url based on the value selected. For testing all the values are set to google. :)

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      {value:"ActionScript", link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"AppleScript",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Asp",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"BASIC",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"C",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"C++",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Clojure",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"COBOL",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"ColdFusion",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Erlang",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Fortran",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Groovy",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Haskell",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Java",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"JavaScript",link:'https://google.com'},
      {value:"Lisp",link:'https://google.com'},
     
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log(ui.item.link);
        window.location.replace(ui.item.link)
      }
    });
  } );
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry for being a newbie at this but is $( "#tags") for the id? and is Tags in var availableTags referring to the same id?

Comment: @GabrielAngel yes, the `#tags` is the id for input field. What it actually does is it inject  jquery UI  autocomplete method to the `input` element who has `tags` ID. You can also refer to jquery UI docs. So does this solved your issue. or do you need more

Comment: And I'm lost again, sorry to be a bother again. I've followed your example and it worked very well, but now i have another problem, the design. specifically the values,  when i input some text into the text field it displays the values related to it, but i can't remove the bullet points from the displayed values or do anything to it. designing  the #tags id in css only works for the box and text within the box and not the suggestions below it. again, i apologize for being bothersome.

Comment: You need to add jquery ui css. Check the packages added in the snippet

Answer (score 1):

i think you need this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry for being a noob at this but is $( "#tags") for the id? and is Tags in var availableTags referring to the same id?

Comment: #tags refering to id